# Отчего может быть невалидна форма Django?

Tags: python, django

В проекте нужно сохранять комментарии под записью Hotel, однако по непонятной причине после нажатия на кнопку происходит обычное перенаправление, данные не записываются в БД. Путем долгих исканий выяснил, что форма не проходит валидность, хотя никаких ошибок не кидает и все условия на заполнение вроде как проходятся. В чем может быть проблема?
Релевантные части кода:

forms:

```
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('post','email','name','body','active')
```

models:

```
class Hotel(models.Model):
    name=models.TextField(max_length=20)
    address=models.TextField(max_length=40)
    desc=models.TextField(max_length=20)
    places=models.IntegerField(max_length=4)
    types=models.TextField()
    facilities=models.TextField()
    owner=models.TextField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Hotel,
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                             related_name='comments')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    email = models.EmailField()
    body = models.TextField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('created',)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Comment by {} on {}'.format(self.name, self.post)
```

views:

```
def review(request,ho_id):
    post = Hotel.objects.get(pk=ho_id)
    comments = post.comments.filter(active=True)
    new_comment = None
    comment_form = CommentForm(data=request.POST)
    if comment_form.is_valid():
        new_comment = comment_form.save(commit=False)
        new_comment.post = post
        new_comment.save()
    try:
        hotell=Hotel.objects.get(pk=ho_id)
    except Hotel.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404("Hotel does not exist")
    return render(request,'review.html',
                  {"hotel":hotell,'post': post,
                   'comments': comments,
                   'new_comment': new_comment,
                   'comment_form': comment_form})
```

review.html (та часть, где форма, в другой - вывод существующих комментариев):

```
{% if new_comment %}
  <h2>Your comment has been added.</h2>
{% else %}
  <h2>Add a new comment</h2>
  <form action="." method="post">
    {{ comment_form.as_p }}
    {% csrf_token %}
    <p><input type="submit" value="Add comment"></p>
  </form>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: У любой формы есть атрибут errors, в котором написано, отчего она может быть невалидна